# Split method of String class returns a string?

Tags: java

According to the [`String.split()` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) the method returns array, so how come the following code compiles?

The `retval` variable inside the for loop is a `String` and not an array but there is no error?

```
public class String_Splitting_Example 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String Str = new String("Welcome-to-Tutorialspoint.com");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Return Value :" );
        for (String retval: Str.split("-"))
        {
            System.out.println(retval);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Str.split("-") is an array. You are using retval to loop through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jared Burrows commented, by writing `for (String retval: Str.split("-"))` you are iterating through each part of the array where retval contains the current String in the array of Strings you got from doing `Str.split`

Answer (score 4):

[`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) returns an array.  It isn't assigning the result of the call to `retval` (notice there's no `=` assignment operator).  Instead, the `:` notation means it's using a [for-each loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/foreach.html) to iterate over the array, and assigning each element in turn to `retval`.

As @nobalG points out there are a number of good resources on StackOverflow as well.  Check out some questions tagged [`java` and `foreach`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+foreach).